# Необходимо отключить прокрутку слайдов pagePiling.js при наведении на div

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Пробовал отключать с помощью скрипта прокрутку полностью, но это ничего не меняет. Слайды как листались, так и листаются:

```
</script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('.wrapper').on('mouseenter', function () {
    $('html,body').on('mousewheel', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    $('.wrapper').on('mousewheel', function (e) {
        var step = 15;
        var direction = e.originalEvent.deltaY > 0 ? 1 : -1;
        $(this).scrollTop($(this).scrollTop() + step * direction);
        console.log(e);
    });
});
$('.wrapper').on('mouseleave', function () {});
    </script>
```

Затем пробовал искать по-другому, конкретно связать поиск решения с плагином pagePiling.js.
В принципе, нашёл как отключить — всего-то в момент наведения на div .wrapper заставить значение **setAllowScrolling** поменяться на ***False***:

```
$.fn.pagepiling.setMouseWheelScrolling(false);
```

В процессе танцев бубнов до меня дошло, что я перестал понимать расклад вещей. Мне это значение *перманентно менять в файле pagePiling.js **не надо***, я же хочу чтобы слайды перелистывались, но только когда курсор мыши находится вне **.wrapper**.
Может стоит объединить эти два решения? Куда тогда в скрипт втыкать часть со сменой значения на false, и как вообще это сделать? ***Помогите.***

Могу залить на гитхаб пэйджс, если потребуется для наглядности

Comment: Я чувствую, что решение где-то на поверхности, но как это сделать — ума не приложу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё же, наверное, правильно будет `$.fn.pagepiling.setAllowScrolling(false);`, а не `$.fn.pagepiling.setMouseWheelScrolling(false);`. В любом случае из вышеизложенной проблемы могу предположить, что `$.fn.pagepiling.setAllowScrolling(false); (или(и) $.fn.pagepiling.setMouseWheelScrolling(false);)` является рабочим решением. Тогда необходимо:

```js
$('.wrapper').on('mouseover', function() {//именно событие mouseover срабатывает при наведении на элемент
  console.log('Наводим на блок .wrapper и отключаем прокрутку слайдов');
  //$.fn.pagepiling.setAllowScrolling(false);
});
$('.wrapper').on('mouseout', function() {//а событие mouseout наоборот - срабатывает, когда мы уводим курсор мыши с элемента
  console.log('Уводим курсор с блока .wrapper и включаем прокрутку слайдов');
  //$.fn.pagepiling.setAllowScrolling(true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
Навести на блок
</div>
```

Comment: Премного благодарен, решение подошло идеально. Но всё же пришлось немного повозиться. 
Чтобы всё работало как часы, нужно было всего-то правильно написать. 
Не **setAllowScroll**, а **setAllowScrolling**. Получается вот такой код:
`$('.wrapper').on('mouseover', function() {
  $.fn.pagepiling.setAllowScrolling(false);
});
$('.wrapper').on('mouseout', function() {
  $.fn.pagepiling.setAllowScrolling(true);
});`

Comment: Тогда я с вашего позволения поправлю ответ, чтобы не запутывать других участников, если кому будет нужно